# Is File Nesting supported in Visual Studio 15.8.4 with aspnetcore projects?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

It is not clear to me whether file nesting in Visual Studio is currently supported for aspnetcore projects.

What I would like to see is *.js and *.js.map nested under *.ts.  It seems like this has worked in the past, but I don't see it now.

I have updated to the latest version of VS, and I have installed the latest File Nesting extension from Mads.

[This blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/07/file-nesting-in-solution-explorer/) seems to say it IS supported, while [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.FileNesting) from Mads says it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just answered my own question: It IS supported.

All I had to do was click on the nesting icon in the Solution explorer to enable it.
[image]